# For the Diffie-Hellman prime and generator, what key length should I use?

Tags: encryption, cryptography, crypto++, diffie-hellman

In the code below, from the Crypto++ wiki, is 128 the number I really should be using?

```cpp
CryptoPP::AutoSeededRandomPool arngA;
CryptoPP::RandomNumberGenerator& rngA = *dynamic_cast<CryptoPP::RandomNumberGenerator *>(&arngA); 
CryptoPP::DH dhA(rngA, 128);
CryptoPP::Integer iPrime = dhA.GetGroupParameters().GetModulus();
CryptoPP::Integer iGenerator = dhA.GetGroupParameters().GetSubgroupGenerator();
```

Comment: The documentation is somewhat opaque to me. I can't tell if 128 is the size in bits of the DH prime, or something else.

Comment: Thanks for this question and the code. The code in the Wiki  is incomplete I think, it misses the dynamic cast. (http://www.cryptopp.com/wiki/Diffie-Hellman)

Answer (score 3):

Integer factorization and discrete logarithm over Z/(pZ) are roughly equally difficult. Therefore the size of the modulus for Diffie-Hellman should be about the same size as you would choose for an RSA modulus. If you are comfortable with a 1024-bit RSA key then you can also be comfortable with a 1024-bit Diffie-Hellman key.

It is not easy to tell if key sizes in crypto++ are measured in bits or bytes.
As Sebastian points out dhA(rngA, 128) may indeed generate a 128 bit Diffie-Hellman key, which would be too small. Going through the code it looks like this is indeed the case.

The size of the generator iGenerator does not affect the security of Diffie-Hellman. (I.e. iGenerator = 2 could be perfectly fine)

Comment: Trying out this code gives a number with roughly 40 digits which corresponds to a 128bit code. Changing the parameter to 1024, iPrime has about 300 digits.